# MacBook Pro (13 inch, mid 2009) crashing hard in Safari; can't run Apple hardware testm

Tags: macos, safari, crash

Several months ago my Mac started crashing. Usually it happens exactly when I click a link in Safari (**Edit:** I tested with Chrome and get the same behavior). I click a link, the page starts to load, then the whole computer hard locks. No beach ball, the cursor does not move, the keyboard is completely unresponsive. After two or three minutes, the screen goes black and it reboots.

I tried creating a new user account and running under that for a while. The whole computer became super responsive. But it didn't solve the issue. I'm able to go for days without crashing while programming, I can do a whole super duper clone of the hard drive without crashing, but bringing Safari into the mix brings the crashes back.

I should point out that it does occasionally crash spontaneously, but usually Safari is running in the background.

I'm running Mavericks because I wanted to rule out a hardware issue before upgrading to Yosemite. (Mostly the Mac has been on a shelf for the past few months because the crashes went from once a week to about once a day and I feared a hard drive issue.)

I've tried:

- Creating a new user and running under that user, as I mentioned above.
- Resetting Safari.
- Creating a super duper clone, booting off the clone, and running disk utility, to rule out HFS+ corruption. That came back totally clean, both times I tried it.
- I also have tried using Apple Hardware Test. Because I did a fresh install of mountain lion onto this SSD, I discovered that didn't work. The hardware is too old to support running AHT over the Internet (that doesn't work either) So I downloaded AHT from https://github.com/upekkha/AppleHardwareTest/blob/master/Readme.markdown and installed it to my boot drive, according to the instructions, but it still does not load Apple Hardware Test.

My questions:

- What the heck is the underlying problem?
- Should I install Yosemite and hope for the best? Upgrade or fresh install?
- How can I get AHT to run?
- I started out thinking this was a disk issue. Is there anything I can do to rule that out? I could replace my wonderful SSD with a (gulp) 5400rpm laptop drive and try that for a while I suppose.
- How is Safari completely hard locking my computer?

I'm looking for next steps and/or advice. Thank you!

Edit: added console log:

`6/15/15 12:11:32.429 AM WindowServer[383]: CGXReleaseWindowList: Invalid window 46 (index 0/2)
6/15/15 12:11:32.430 AM WindowServer[383]: CGXReleaseWindowList: Invalid window 45 (index 1/2)
6/15/15 12:11:33.102 AM sandboxd[245]: ([532]) com.apple.intern(532) deny mach-lookup com.apple.CalendarAgentLauncher
6/15/15 12:11:34.715 AM parentalcontrolsd[646]: StartObservingFSEvents [849:] -- *** StartObservingFSEvents started event stream
6/15/15 12:11:36.911 AM WindowServer[383]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Xcode" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
6/15/15 12:11:37.806 AM WindowServer[383]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Xcode" after 1.90 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
6/15/15 12:11:39.257 AM WindowServer[383]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Dropbox" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
6/15/15 12:11:39.372 AM WindowServer[383]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Dropbox" after 1.12 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
6/15/15 12:11:40.131 AM Dropbox[610]: PyObjCPointer created: at 0x6a9fc88 of type ^{OpaqueJSContext=}
6/15/15 12:11:42.756 AM GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[617]: -[KeystoneDaemon logServiceState] GoogleSoftwareUpdate daemon (1.2.0.7709) vending:
    com.google.Keystone.Daemon.UpdateEngine: 1 connection(s)
    com.google.Keystone.Daemon.Administration: 0 connection(s)
6/15/15 12:11:43.912 AM ipcserver[682]: Valve Steam ipcserver started: 1.04
6/15/15 12:11:44.495 AM WindowServer[383]: disable_update_timeout: UI updates were forcibly disabled by application "Xcode" for over 1.00 seconds. Server has re-enabled them.
6/15/15 12:11:47.047 AM WindowServer[383]: common_reenable_update: UI updates were finally reenabled by application "Xcode" after 3.55 seconds (server forcibly re-enabled them after 1.00 seconds)
6/15/15 12:11:50.000 AM kernel[0]: fsevents: watcher dbfseventsd (pid: 698) - Using /dev/fsevents directly is unsupported.  Migrate to FSEventsFramework
6/15/15 12:11:55.022 AM GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon[617]: -[KeystoneDaemon main] GoogleSoftwareUpdateDaemon inactive, shutdown.
6/15/15 12:11:56.287 AM Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[713]: BUG in libdispatch client: kevent[EVFILT_VNODE] add: "Bad file descriptor" - 0x9
6/15/15 12:11:56.460 AM Interface Builder Cocoa Touch Tool[713]: assertion failed: 13F1077: libxpc.dylib + 29453 [464E62EA-4CF2-3FEF-9C17-692AD8D66AA8]: 0x8d
6/15/15 12:11:59.428 AM Dropbox[610]: The function 'CGContextClear' is obsolete and will be removed in an upcoming update. Unfortunately, this application, or a library it uses, is using this obsolete function, and is thereby contributing to an overall degradation of system performance.
6/15/15 12:12:01.809 AM Dropbox[610]: ICARegisterForEventNotification-Has been deprecated since 10.5.  Calls to this function in the future may crash this application.  Please move to ImageCaptureCore
6/15/15 12:12:57.612 AM com.apple.WebKit.Networking[497]: ERROR: ForceShrinkPersistentStore_NoLock -delete- We do not have a BLOB or TEXT column type.  Instead, we have 5.
6/15/15 12:13:07.353 AM com.apple.SecurityServer[15]: Session 100040 created
6/15/15 12:13:15.104 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[738]: CKSoftwareMap: Registering with Daemon
6/15/15 12:13:27.450 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[745]: CKSoftwareMap: Registering with Daemon
6/15/15 12:13:38.490 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[744]: CKSoftwareMap: Registering with Daemon
6/15/15 12:13:41.779 AM Scroll Reverser[608]: -_scrollPhase is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -momentumPhase.
6/15/15 12:13:48.885 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[742]: CKSoftwareMap: Registering with Daemon
6/15/15 12:14:00.989 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[744]: ERROR: ITSExceptionHandler: {message:"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#header").addClassName')", url:"https://se.itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/FC5B/da-storefront-autoinstallations.js", lineNumber:"381"}
6/15/15 12:14:06.452 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[744]: ERROR: ITSExceptionHandler: {message:"TypeError: 'null' is not an object (evaluating 'document.querySelector("#header").addClassName')", url:"https://se.itunes.apple.com/htmlResources/FC5B/da-storefront-autoinstallations.js", lineNumber:"381"}
6/15/15 12:14:15.646 AM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.5FC80018-A2E0-4F0F-8730-89114D0E147B[738]) Exited with code: 1
6/15/15 12:15:56.211 AM com.apple.WebKit.WebContent[765]: BUG in libdispatch: 13F1077 - 2899 - 0x4
6/15/15 12:15:56.216 AM com.apple.launchd[1]: (com.apple.WebKit.WebContent.84EA8D77-EAAC-4A33-8F08-283E50B42124[765]) Exited with code: 1
6/15/15 12:16:12.079 AM spindump[758]: Saved diag report for powerstats version com.apple.SystemStats.Daily to /Library/Logs/DiagnosticReports/powerstats_2015-06-15-001611_Johns-MacBook-Pro-2.diag
6/15/15 12:20:20.379 AM com.apple.IconServicesAgent[777]: IconServicesAgent launched.
6/15/15 12:20:20.413 AM distnoted[780]: assertion failed: 13F1077: liblaunch.dylib + 25164 [A40A0C7B-3216-39B4-8AE0-B5D3BAF1DA8A]: 0x25
6/15/15 12:20:24.977 AM launchservicesd[70]: Application App:"Terminal" asn:0x0-2e02e pid:412 refs=7 @ 0x7fb112604bd0 tried to be brought forward, but isn't in fPermittedFrontApps ( ( "LSApplication:0x0-0x7f07f pid=775 "SecurityAgent"")), so denying. : LASSession.cp #1481 SetFrontApplication() q=LSSession 100023/0x186b7 queue
6/15/15 12:20:24.977 AM WindowServer[383]: [cps/setfront] Failed setting the front application to Terminal, psn 0x0-0x2e02e, securitySessionID=0x186b7, err=-13066`

Comment: Did you try to isolate the problem to Safari by using another browser?

Comment: To be honest that never occurred to me. I'll give it a shot and see how it goes.

Comment: I was able to crash it the exact same way with Chrome. After about fifteen minutes of moderate web browsing, I typed a search in the chrome address bar, hit enter, and a moment later it just completely locked up.

Comment: OK, so it is not a browser. Now we need you to provide copy of your console log at the time of the event. 50-100 lines